# Signing PDF document with qualified certificate - smartcard

Tags: java, pdf, applet, smartcard, pkcs#11

I have a problem with my applet for signing PDF documents using smartcard. It works fine for not qualified certificates but won't for qualified. I'm using SunPKCS11 provider. It's CryptoTech card. Here's part of code, where i'm trying to operate on this provider:

```
String pkcs11config = "name = " + PROVIDER + "\nlibrary = \"" + value + "\""; 
byte[] pkcs11configBytes = pkcs11config.getBytes();
final ByteArrayInputStream configStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(pkcs11configBytes);
pkcs11Provider = new sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11(configStream);
Security.addProvider(pkcs11Provider);
```

And here is code, when the problem occured:

```
final KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(TYPE, pkcs11Provider);
        keyStore.load(null, PIN);
```

And the constants:

```
public static final String PROVIDER = "CryptoTech";
private static final String TYPE = "PKCS11";
```

Here's exception stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: load failed
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:763)
    at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
    at pl.emsi.sign.card.CardManager.getKey(CardManager.java:165)
    at pl.emsi.sign.logic.DocumentLogic$1.success(DocumentLogic.java:79)
    at pl.emsi.sign.card.CardManager$1.driverSelected(CardManager.java:92)
    at pl.emsi.sign.card.CardManager$2.driverSelected(CardManager.java:121)
    at pl.emsi.sign.card.CardManager$7.actionPerformed(CardManager.java:414)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1238)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.login(P11KeyStore.java:849)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11KeyStore.engineLoad(P11KeyStore.java:753)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_PIN_LOCKED
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_Login(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11.login(SunPKCS11.java:1222)
    ... 56 more
```

I've already checked that the PIN isn't locked, because other application (no need to mention the name of this application) signs the PDF document without any problems. The PIN is 100% correct, also.

If there's some information missing, please, let me know.

**EDIT1:** 
By: "It works fine for not qualified certificates but won't for qualified" i meant that the not qualified certificates was placed on different smartcards than this qualified certificate.

Comment: Smartcards sometimes require different pins for different usages. If a smart card e.g. has key material for both qualified and and merely advanced signatures (the first for signing contracts, the second for authenticating at an electronic door lock), the respective PINs usually can be chosen independently.

Comment: It might help to use some pkcs11 logger (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/jariq/pkcs11-logger)) to inspect what is going on (you can compare what different programs vs. different cards do and spot the difference). Good luck!

Comment: @vlp Isn't that logger "pay-to-use" for non open source applications?

Comment: @HubertPopiołkiewicz (To be honest) I don't know. I use a similar logger I have from SafeNet and not this one -- but this one is the only publicly available I am aware of...

Comment: @vlp I have changed the license of pkcs11-logger to a more permissive Apache 2.0 license so it is now completely free even for commercial use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Okay, I found a solution for my problem.

It turned out that the provider was trying to use card's slot with id 0 by default. Card, at which there was problem, have non qualified certificates on three first slots. Tokens on these slots isn't initialized. The qualified cert I was trying to use is placed on fourth slot.

I used `IAIK PKCS11 Wrapper` to get info about `Tokens` of this card. Here's code sample:

```
        try {
            Module module = Module.getInstance(value);
            module.initialize(null);
            Slot[] slots = module.getSlotList(true);
            TokenInfo[] infos = new TokenInfo[slots.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
                infos[i] = slots[i].getToken().getTokenInfo();
            }
            printTokenInfos(infos);
            if (slots.length == 0) {
                System.err.println("No token available!");
                return;
            }
        } catch (TokenException | IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        [...]

    private void printTokenInfos(TokenInfo[] infos) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (TokenInfo info : infos) {
            System.out.println("Token: " + counter++);
            System.out.println(info);
        }
    }

    //"value" passed to Module's getInstance method is th path for .dll module 
    //used for one's type of card.
```

From this place I can determine which slot I should use. It can be accomplished by adding `slotListIndex` parameter to Provider's configuration input stream. E.g.

```
    String pkcs11config = "name = " + PROVIDER + "\nlibrary = \"" + value + "\"\nslotListIndex = " + slotIndex;
```

Helpful sites for this issue:
[IAIK JCA/JCE](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core_Crypto_Toolkits/JCA_JCE)
https://javaczysen.blogspot.com/ - unfortunately, only in polish.

Answer (score 1):

Pass null in place of PIN parameter in keyStore.load method(keyStore.load(null, null)) will result in password prompt from respective token driver. You can validate the PIN this way...

Comment: Already checked this method by providing PasswordCallback - still the same problem.